# Geolocalização em PHP

Tags: php

Olá, gostaria de saber se tem como eu pegar a localização de um usuário que acessar minha aplicação em PHP, tipo, retornar algo tipo assim:

País: Brasil
Estado: bláblá
Cidade: Narnia

e se possivel que ainda desse a atitude e longitude

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar a API [deste site](http://ipinfo.io/). Aparentemente a versão gratuita permite até 1000 requisições diárias. Com PHP, o código pode ser bem simples:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
var_dump($details);
```

O resultado é algo como:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
  ["ip"]=> string(13) "..."
  ["hostname"]=> string(11) "No Hostname"
  ["city"]=> string(8) "Curitiba"
  ["region"]=> string(6) "Parana"
  ["country"]=> string(2) "BR"
  ["loc"]=> string(17) "..."
  ["org"]=> string(30) "AS18881 TELEFÔNICA BRASIL S.A"
}
```

Alguns dados foram omitidos por questões de segurança.